# Как получить все переводы в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно получить все все переводы из файлов локализации по выбранному языку в виде многомерного массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$lang_paginate= Lang::get('pagination');` - вернет массив файла pagination

`$next = Lang::get('pagination.count')` - вернет только элемент кол-во

Если вы хотите получить все файлы с переводами вам придется создать метод, который пройдется например по названиям файлов в папке языков, выберет их и объединит массивы